# JavaScript determine the device, and add image to message.confirm

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone

I am trying to find out the device (Android/iPhone/PC etc...) that the user is viewing my site on, If they are on Android I want to give them the option to Download the Android App, and if on iPhone give them the option to download the iPhone APP.

I do have something that works for Android:

```
// JavaScript Document
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    if (window.confirm("Would you like to download, APP_NAME Android App")) { 
        // Redirect to Android-site?
        window.open("https://play.google.com/store/APP_URL_HERE", "Re-directing you to the Android Store!");
    }   
}
```

Questions:
Can I add an image to the window.confirm box, and how.

Is this the correct way for doing this, if not can anyone suggest a better way.

Thanks

G

Answer (score 1):

`confirm` and `alert` are very simple, in-built functionality not suitable for anything more than a simple string...  I'd suggest building a `modal` of some sort if you want to prompt the user with more elegance.

A simple div, positioned absolutely in the center of the device, with a nice border and drop-shadow always seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Alex, will look into that now.